# How can I prevent a compiled function from using uncompiled evaluation?

Tags: compile

I write a code that creates a compiled function, and then call that function over and over to generate a list.  I run this code on a remote server via a batch job, and will run several instances of it.  Sometimes when I make changes to the code, I make a mistake, and inside the compiled function is an undefined variable, such that when the function is called I get the following error messages (repeated several times)

```
 CompiledFunction::cfse: Compiled expression w should be a machine-size complex number.

 CompiledFunction::cfex: Could not complete external evaluation at instruction 18; proceeding with uncompiled evaluation.
```

This causes massive memory usage (which puts me on the system administrator's bad side), and the results are garbage if since there was a mistake in the code.  Is there any way to force the code to abort and quit the program rather than proceed with uncompiled evaluation?

Comment: you can also do `fc = Compile[{{z, _Real}}, Sin[z]]; f[x_?NumericQ] := fc[x]`

Comment: But that only fixes it if the function argument isn't numeric.  My mistake involved an undefined variable inside the expression I feed to `Compile`.

Comment: OK, I thought you were worried about passing the wrong argument, not actually forgetting to localise your variables.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Adding this option for `Compile`

```
"RuntimeOptions" -> {"RuntimeErrorHandler" ->Function[Throw[$Failed]]}
```

will cause it to abort evaluation if any error messages come up.  To more directly control the memory usage, and stay on the sysadmin's good side, wrap the call to the compiled function with `MemoryConstrained`, which causes it to abort if the memory goes above a certain threshold.

Answer (score 3):

You can add

```
RuntimeOptions -> {"EvaluateSymbolically" -> False}
```

to your `Compile` function.
Consult [RuntimeOptions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RuntimeOptions.html) for more details.

Comment: Using version 9,this doesn't seem to change anything.  I added that option to `Compile` but I get the same error message.

Comment: I don't know why that didn't work, but I looked into `RuntimeOptions` and found this, which seems to work just fine:  `"RuntimeOptions" -> {"RuntimeErrorHandler" ->Function[Throw[$Failed]]}`
Thanks for your help

Comment: This doesn't remove the mistake in your code, but it should solve your memory issue.

Comment: Totally, I still have to go in and fix the issue, but this stops it from grabbing all the memory in the (inevitable) chance that I make a mistake like this.

Comment: @JasonB, please add that solution as an answer - it is valuable and shouldn't be hidden away in a comment.

Comment: @JasonB, does using the `RuntimeErrorHandler` also solve your memory problem?

Comment: @Karsten7., yes it does since it doesn't try to populate the list symbolically.

Comment: @JasonB Are you aware of `SetSystemOptions["CompileOptions" -> "CompileReportExternal"->True]`? If not, it might be useful in your case (it warns you at compile time if you reference an external variable). I might have misunderstood the problem you are trying to solve, though.

Comment: @acl, I like that as an option (I would want to add that to my init.m file, right?), but when I run it headless on the server I might not see the error when compiling.  I know my problem is the result of sloppy programming (I had to look up what it means to "localize my variables").

Comment: @JasonB OK, if you only ever run it headless then you won't see it. For what it's worth, what I do is write code on my laptop, make sure it works on small example, then send the whole thing to bigger machines. But if you can't, then the solutions here might be the only way (I do have it in my `init.m` as you said).